# Python program not working..The main part keep showing error

Tags: python, oop

```
class point:
    def __init__(self,z,d):
        self.x = z
        self.y = d
    def display(self,z,d):
        self.x = self.z
        self.y = self.d
    def setX(self, z):
        self.x = z
    def setY(self, d):
        self.y = d
    def getX(self):
       return self.x
    def getY(self):
       return self.y
    def show(self):
       print(self.x)
       print(self.y)

p1 = point() //error
print("Point P1:")
p1.show()
print("Updated value:")
p1.display(5, 6)
p1.setX(9)
p1.setY(4)
p1.show()
print("Point P2:")
p2=point()
p2.setX(9)
p2.setY(4)
p2.show()
print("Updated value:")
p2.display(6, 3)
p2.show()
```

My program keep showing me error that z and d are missing in the object section,,i donno how to correct it i keep trying but more n more errors keeps showing up.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P:\xxxyyy.py", line 29, in <module>
    p1 = point() //error
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'z' and 'd'
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: When asking about code that produces an exception, please include the complete Traceback in the question: copy and paste it then format it as code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget to pass in `z` and `d` in the constructor, eg:

```
p1 = point(1,2)
```

Also, in the `display` function, you try to set `self.x` to `self.z` and `self.y` to `self.d`. `self.z` and `self.d` don't exist (self means it should be a class attribute, which it isn't), you should instead use the function's input parameters:

```
self.x = z
self.y = d
```

Comment: ... or give those parameters [default values](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values) in the method definition.

Comment: Yep! I just assumed he meant to use the function parameters since they are there and match up to `self.z` and `self.d`. Whichever way makes more sense is the better way

Comment: i did try putting 1,2 in it,, it wasn't working with that too..also the self thing i wrote it like the statement u told me bout. but since it was showing error so i changed it(silly me duh)

Answer (score 0):

```
class point: 
    def __init__(self,z,d): 
        self.x = z 
        self.y = d 
    def display(self,z,d): 
        self.x = z #not self.z
        self.y = d #not self.d
    def setX(self, z): 
        self.x = z 
    def setY(self, d): 
        self.y = d 
    def getX(self): 
       return self.x 
    def getY(self): 
       return self.y 
    def show(self): 
       print(self.x) 
       print(self.y)
```

First fix this, you are updating with `display` using two new variables that its taking in, so we just cast those variables not `self.z` / `self.d`

```
p1 = point(1,2)
print("Point P1:")
p1.show()
```

Create your instance with values that it needs `__ini__(self, z, d)`  needs a `z and d` value

```
print("Updated value:")
p1.display(5, 6)
p1.setX(9)
p1.setY(4)
p1.show()
```

If `p1.display` is updating the values to `5,6` then why update them again with `setX`/`setY` pretty much you are making `z=5, d=6` then `z=9 d=4`

And then you just repeat these small errors for `p2`

Comment: thanks for explaining.. about the set n get thing i had the assignment to do it in both ways. So thatsy i used display n also set n get fuctions

Comment: np would appreciate if this solved your problem if you checked solved :)